# Is there a way to prevent updates (painting) to a `WebView` and then re-enable them?

Tags: javafx

### Is there a way to prevent updates (painting) to a `WebView` and then re-enable them?

e.g.

1. disable painting
2. set new html content
3. re-enable painting

### Why I'd like to do this

because my html is *jumpy* the elements will all be in the same positions on the HTML page after as before but during the update of the HTML they will move around a bit. Since I'm refreshing the HTML on a periodic basis, it is quite annoying to have it jump around often.

Comment: This question is kind of vague.  You might want to clarify it some more or add some example code or link to an example site.  Also, perhaps the answer might be generic html5/javascript related and not strictly related just to WebView, so you might want to also tag it javascript to reach a wider audience.  While typing this I did think of an answer anyway, so I'll paste that :-)

Comment: No js involved, simply I'm not so great at javafx and don't really understand how to turn on and off painting of controls. So that's why I asked. I mean yes js is why it jumps (using something called datatables.net) but it's not really important to the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: hey thanks, your javascript comment got me thinking.. after so now I solved my problem purely with javascript.. The datatable I was using had sample code using `$(document).ready...` I simply removed that so that it executes sooner, and the jumpiness disappeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real painting on/off switch either in WebView or in general for JavaFX (as far as I know), but perhaps the workaround below might help.

You could always:

1. [snapshot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.util.Callback-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) the WebView, to create an image.
2. Replace the WebView with the snapshot image.
3. Set new html content.
4. Replace the snapshot image with the WebView.

To do this, you could put the snapshot image and the WebView in a StackPane, with the WebView on top and trigger [`setVisible(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-) on the WebView when you want to hide it and set new html content and trigger `setVisible(true)` once you want the new content to be seen.

You might want to use some synchronization to know when the newly set html content has finished rendering either by a message from the JavaScript to Java or by monitoring the html events in Java (doing such is beyond the scope of this post).  There might also be some issues with the WebView detecting it is not actually visible and then deciding to be lazy because of an optimization and not repaint itself for updated html content until it is made visible again (not sure I haven't tried it).

Anyway, perhaps give this technique a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Ah that's a pity.. thanks for the answer. It's in a tab but I guess that wouldn't help anything either